# How to receive "v4l2-ctl --stream-to-host" stream from a machine on the same LAN on said host for use with, e.g., video conferencing software?

Tags: linux, camera, v4l2loopback, streams

There is [an example](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/1967306) that streams a webcam to another computer by piping a V4L2 stream into netcat (`v4l2-ctl --stream-to - | nc <host> <port>`), and this works, but it feels redundant when `v4l2-ctl --stream-to-host <host>[:<port>]` exists.

I was able to capture and display the `--stream-to-host` stream via `qvidcap -p` as described in the [`v4l2-ctl` man page example section](https://www.mankier.com/1/v4l2-ctl#Examples), but am stumped when trying to pipe it into `v4l2-loopback` (via FFmpeg) for use with video conferencing software on the receiving machine.

I have tried various combinations of parameters to `v4l2-ctl`, including `--stream-from-host`, `--stream-loop`, `--stream-poll` and `--stream-mmap`, but `v4l2-ctl --help-all` is too terse for me. Ironically, I was able to receive a stream (albeit garbled beyond recognition) when receiving with netcat and piping it to ffmpeg (`nc -l <port> | ffmpeg <format options> -f v4l2 /dev/video0`.

How can I make an incoming stream created via `v4l2-ctl --stream-mmap --stream-to-host <host>[:<port>]` available to video conferencing software via `v4l2-loopback`?